# SQL - Set Decimal Value Using Money

Tags: sql

I am trying to take an existing column with money values in it, and use those to set a value in another column which is a decimal.  As an example, if I have "8.65" as my money value, I am trying to set a decimal value/column associated with that same record as "8.6500000000".  In my case, I need 10 decimal points of precision.

This is the code I tried which failed to do anything (it did not give an error, it just did not update any records):

```
SET abc_PaidDecimal = CAST(abc_PaidAmnt AS DECIMAL(16,10))
WHERE abc_PaidDecimal <> CAST(abc_PaidAmnt AS DECIMAL(16,10))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this behavior if your abc_PaidDecimal contains NULL. NULLs cannot be compared to any other value, the only valid comparison for them is to use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL.

So, try adding `or abc_PaidDecimal IS NULL` to your `WHERE` clause

Comment: I had to change my where clause in a way which I did not specify in my original question.  However, while all of the comments were helpful in some way, this answer was the one that led me down the path I needed.

Answer (score 0):

8.65 and 8.6500000000000 are the same number.

Also 1 and 00001 are the same numbers. So, in your `where` clause, `<>` will always give `false`. That's why you're not updating anything

If you want to update all your fields, with this transformation, remove the `Where` clause

Comment: Removing the clause did allow my query to execute, so that was an important point.  However, my query requires a where clause, in my specific case.

Comment: then, you have to specify the correct where clause. When you want to update ? Your actual where clause will never update anything

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to explicitly Cast money  to decimal ,it will be converted implicitly
and stored as decimal(16,10)

however to do comparison between 8.65 and 8.650000  cast both sides to varchar(26)
**when** you don't want them to be treated equal.

```
WHERE   CAST(abc_PaidDecimal AS VARCHAR(26)) <> CAST(abc_PaidAmnt AS VARCHAR(26))
```

an example

```
DECLARE @v1 MONEY = 23.25
        ,@v2 DECIMAL(18,6)= 23.250000

SELECT @v1 , @v2
IF  @v1 = @v2
SELECT 'same value before cast'
ELSE 
SELECT 'different value before cast'

SELECT CAST(@v1 AS VARCHAR(26)) , CAST(@v2 AS VARCHAR(26))
IF  CAST(@v1 AS VARCHAR(26)) = CAST(@v2 AS VARCHAR(26))
SELECT 'same value after cast'
ELSE 
SELECT 'different value after cast'
```